# All possible combinations of an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an string array

```
{"ted", "williams", "golden", "voice", "radio"}
```

and I want all possible combinations of these keywords in the following form:

```
{"ted",
 "williams",
 "golden", 
 "voice", 
 "radio",
 "ted williams", 
 "ted golden", 
 "ted voice", 
 "ted radio", 
 "williams golden",
 "williams voice", 
 "williams radio", 
 "golden voice", 
 "golden radio", 
 "voice radio",
 "ted williams golden", 
 "ted williams voice", 
 "ted williams radio", 
 .... }
```

I've been going for hours with no effective result (side effect of high-level programming ??).

I know the solution should be obvious but I'm stuck, honestly ! Solutions in Java/C# are accepted.

**EDIT**:

1. It's not a homework
2. "ted williams" and "williams ted" are considered the same, so I want "ted williams" only

**EDIT 2**: after reviewing the link in the answer, it turns out that Guava users can have the powerset method in com.google.common.collect.Sets

Comment: Looks like this was answered [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx).

Comment: Searching StackOverflow for `array combinations` gives me "5,000+" results (167 pages), with many results on the first page being this exact same question, and most of those are tagged as `homework`

Comment: No it's not a homework, I have a list of annotations and want to exploit top web pages containing these combinations

Comment: I'm not looking for a cartesian product of 2 arrays

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**EDIT:** As FearUs pointed out, a better solution is to use Guava's [Sets.powerset(Set set)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet(java.util.Set)).

**EDIT 2:** Updated links.

---

Quick and dirty translation of [this solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20100206003803/http://davidtran.doublegifts.com/blog/?p=144):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<String>> powerSet = new LinkedList<List<String>>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= args.length; i++)
        powerSet.addAll(combination(Arrays.asList(args), i));

    System.out.println(powerSet);
}

public static <T> List<List<T>> combination(List<T> values, int size) {

    if (0 == size) {
        return Collections.singletonList(Collections.<T> emptyList());
    }

    if (values.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    List<List<T>> combination = new LinkedList<List<T>>();

    T actual = values.iterator().next();

    List<T> subSet = new LinkedList<T>(values);
    subSet.remove(actual);

    List<List<T>> subSetCombination = combination(subSet, size - 1);

    for (List<T> set : subSetCombination) {
        List<T> newSet = new LinkedList<T>(set);
        newSet.add(0, actual);
        combination.add(newSet);
    }

    combination.addAll(combination(subSet, size));

    return combination;
}
```

Test:

```
$ java PowerSet ted williams golden
[[ted], [williams], [golden], [ted, williams], [ted, golden], [williams, golden], [ted, williams, golden]]
$
```

Comment: Yes Thank you, that's exactly what I neede, tested and worked perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. saved my time!!

Comment: Broken link to original source. And broken link to guava doc.

Comment: also notice that the resulting array will be exponential in input size, that means your resulting array will easily take several gigabytes for only 30 input words, so avoid this approach if you expect any larger input arrays.

Answer (score 9):

I just faced this problem and wasn't really happy with the StackExchange answers posted, so here's my answer.  This returns all combinations from an array of `Port` objects.  I'll leave it to the reader to adapt to whatever class you're using (or make it generic).

This version does not use recursion.

```
public static Port[][] combinations ( Port[] ports ) {
    
    List<Port[]> combinationList = new ArrayList<Port[]>();
    // Start i at 1, so that we do not include the empty set in the results
    for ( long i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, ports.length); i++ ) {
        List<Port> portList = new ArrayList<Port>();
        for ( int j = 0; j < ports.length; j++ ) {
            if ( (i & (long) Math.pow(2, j)) > 0 ) {
                // Include j in set
                portList.add(ports[j]);
            }
        }
        combinationList.add(portList.toArray(new Port[0]));
    }
    return combinationList.toArray(new Port[0][0]);
}
```

See solution by @Aison on this page for a more optimized version.

Comment: Using nested functions was loading up my heap space to the point of out-of-heap-space-exceptions. It also went through 98% of my cpu. This function however barely scratches both the heap or my cpu +1

Comment: I'm curious who downvoted this question and why, five years after the fact and without comment?  I'm happy to improve the answer if you have suggestions.

Comment: Hej Matthew - this answer was downvoted by accident. Sorry for that! If you edit and give me info I can undo that. Vote is locked currently.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint:

```
All-Subsets(X) = {union for all y in X: All-Subsets(X-y)} union {X}
```

Answer (score 3):

My optimized solution is based on the solution provided by Matthew McPeak. This version avoids unnecessary array copies.

```
public static <T> T[][] combinations(T[] a) {

    int len = a.length;
    if (len > 31)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int numCombinations = (1 << len) - 1;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[][] combinations = (T[][]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), numCombinations);

    // Start i at 1, so that we do not include the empty set in the results
    for (int i = 1; i <= numCombinations; i++) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] combination = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(),
                Integer.bitCount(i));

        for (int j = 0, ofs = 0; j < len; j++)
            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                combination[ofs++] = a[j];

        combinations[i - 1] = combination;
    }

    return combinations;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would you please comment on my answer to indicate where the unnecessary array copies are?

Comment: Sadly I can not comment your answer directly, since my reputation is still too low. But you create array copies with the toArray calls to portList and combinationList. And altough size of the final result is known at beginning, you use ArrayList and let them dynamically grow, which implies array copies also.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class AllPossibleCombinations {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a={"ted", "williams", "golden"};           
    List<List<String>> list = new AllPossibleElementCombinations().getAllCombinations(Arrays.asList(a));
    for (List<String> arr:list) {
        for(String s:arr){
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public List<List<String>> getAllCombinations(List<String> elements) {
    List<List<String>> combinationList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for ( long i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, elements.size()); i++ ) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for ( int j = 0; j < elements.size(); j++ ) {
            if ( (i & (long) Math.pow(2, j)) > 0 ) {
                list.add(elements.get(j));
            }
        }
        combinationList.add(list);
    }
    return combinationList;
}

}
```

output:

ted

williams

tedwilliams

golden

tedgolden

williamsgolden

tedwilliamsgolden

Answer (score 0):

```
package rnd;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Rnd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a[] = {"ted", "williams", "golden", "voice", "radio"};
        ArrayList<String> result =new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0 ;i< a.length; i++){
            String s = "";
            for(int j =i ; j < a.length; j++){
                s += a[j] + " " ;
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not get all combinations.  For example, it will not produce the combination "ted radio".

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but i didn't find an answer that fullfill my needs. So using the idea of power sets, and ordered permutations of the guava library, im able to obtain an array of all the combinations of elements inside my original array.

What i wanted was this:

If i have an array with three strings

```
ArrayList<String> tagsArray = new ArrayList<>(Array.asList("foo","bar","cas"));
```

I want to have all the posible combinations of the elements inside an array:

```
{"foo","bar","cas","foobar","foocas","barfoo","barcas","casfoo","casbar","foobarcas","casbarfoo","barcasfoo" . . . . . }
```

So for getting to this result i implemented the next code, using the google's guava lib:

```
  import static com.google.common.collect.Collections2.orderedPermutations;
  import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

  public void createTags(){

    Set<String> tags =  new HashSet<>();
    tags.addAll(tagsArray);
    Set<Set<String>> tagsSets = Sets.powerSet(tags);

    for (Set<String> sets : tagsSets) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.addAll(sets);
        if (!myList.isEmpty()) {
            for (List<String> perm : orderedPermutations(myList)) {
                System.out.println(perm);
                String myTag = Joiner.on("").join(perm);
                tagsForQuery.add(myTag);
            }
        }
    }

    for (String hashtag : tagsForQuery) {
        System.out.println(hashtag);
    }
}
```

I hope this help somebody, this wasn't for a homework, but for a android app.

Comment: Your'e using a call to `orderedPermutations()` which isn't part of this answer. Also, you're adding to `tagsForQuery` which isn't mentioned anywhere either.