# How to get all the possible combinations in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

I have an array (java) like this:

> `String arrName[] = {"John","Paul","Luke","Ana"};`

and i want to have an output like this:

```
JohnPaul
JohnLuke
JohnAna
PaulJohn
PualLuke
PaulAna
LukeJohn
LukePaul
LukeAna
AnaJohn
AnaPaul
AnaLuke
```

can someone help me???

Comment: You need some combination algorythm to do this [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) here is the libary to solve your problem [combinatoricslib](https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/)

Comment: you want to know solution or just that someone can help or not :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [All possible combinations of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162254/all-possible-combinations-of-an-array)

Comment: i just want to add 2 elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this :-

```
for(int i=0 ; i < arrName.length ; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< arrName.length; j++){
        if(j != i){
            System.out.println(arrName[i]+arrName[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could i know why my answer is downvoted

Comment: Its poorly formatted (text and indentation).

Comment: actually this is better than the one `it will give less combintion in case he has duplicate entry in array. var array Name = {"John" "Paul", "John"}. this code will skip johnjohn`

Comment: it's ok if there are same Names like 'JohnJohn' unless their indexes are different

Answer (score 1):

Do a cross product between the array and a copy of the array in the form of a nested foreach loop. skip the names that are equal to eachother

```
String[] copyArrName = arrName;
for (String name : arrName){
    for (String otherName: copyArrName){
        if(name != otherName)
            System.out.println(name + " " + otherName); 
    }
}
```

this will give you the desired output

Comment: it will give less combintion in case he has duplicate entry in array. var array Name = {"John" "Paul", "John"}. this code will skip johnjohn.

Comment: Good point, rather we should use the reference string comparison rather than the string equality comparison. edits incoming!