# How can I get all possible combinations of element in set? (power set)

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, formula, permutation

I have a array of number:

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3);
```

The order does not mean anything.  If the numbers given were 1, 2 and 3, then I would want to receive this as a result:

```
1
2
3
1 2
1 3
2 3
1 2 3
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please add your code to the question

Comment: I have not tried anything yet.  Not sure where to start besides writing out a function but if there is a ready made function out there already, I'd rather use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array 

This solution is close to what I need, but without the extra combinations with different orders.

Comment: already resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617055/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-php/2617080#2617080

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162254/all-possible-combinations-of-an-array

Comment: @kmgkumar this link to the solution in JAVA -> I guess OP need PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following recursion function:

```
function powerSet($arr) {
    if (!$arr) return array([]);
    $firstElement = array_shift($arr);
    $recursionCombination = powerSet($arr);
    $currentResult = [];
    foreach($recursionCombination as $comb) {
        $currentResult[] = array_merge($comb, [$firstElement]);
    }
    return array_merge($currentResult, $recursionCombination );
}
```

Now  `print_r(powerSet([1,2,3]));` will give you all those option as arrays.

Edited with adding option of empty array as powerSet

Comment: Nice and clean. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an error in this code?  Is the call to `comb()` supposed to be a call to `powerSet()`?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - you are correct - probably got lost in one of the editing... fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @dWinder — Thanks for this answer, BTW.  Just what I was looking for as it is a brain-bender to write I did not want to have to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved with:

[PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)

Then added my own function to clean it up:

```
        function clean_depth_picker(&$result) {
                $results = array();
                foreach($result as $value) {
                        if ( substr_count($value, " ") == 0 ) {
                                $results[] = $value;
                        } else {
                                $arr = explode(" ", $value);
                                sort($arr);
                                $key = implode(" ", $arr);
                                if ( !in_array($key, $results) )
                                        $results[] = $key;
                        }
                }
                $result = $results;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I found it on a old SO post or Github gist.

```
<?php
function uniqueCombination($in, $minLength = 1, $max = 2000) {
    $count = count($in);
    $members = pow(2, $count);
    $return = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $members; $i ++) {
        $b = sprintf("%0" . $count . "b", $i);
        $out = array();
        for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j ++) {
            $b{$j} == '1' and $out[] = $in[$j];
        }
        count($out) >= $minLength && count($out) <= $max and $return[] = $out;
        }
    return $return;
}

$numbers = array(1,2,3);
$return = uniqueCombination($numbers);
sort($return);
print_r(array_map(function($v){ return implode(" ", $v); }, $return));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array (
   [0] => 1 
   [1] => 2 
   [2] => 3 
   [3] => 1 2 
   [4] => 1 3 
   [5] => 2 3 
   [6] => 1 2 3 
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/lec2F

Comment: This taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092781/finding-the-subsets-of-an-array-in-php - :D

Comment: No,I found it on a gist I guess on a very old post of SO