# Recursive challenge in JS combining all possible array keys in true | false versions, I attach the input and output

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, recursion, logic

I have found many solutions about all posible combinations between array values but I need something different, I hope you could support me. Basically is to create all posible objects that combine array keys with true|false values, something like this:

Input: (Should return an array of 32 objects, 2exp5, two posible values in 5 keys)

```
let properties = ['arm','lens','season','food','size'];
```

Output:

```
let combinations = [
  {"arm": "false","lens": "false","season": "false","food": "false","size": "false"}
  {"arm": "false","lens": "false","season": "false","food": "false","size": "true"}
  {"arm": "false","lens": "false","season": "false","food": "true","size": "true"}
  {"arm": "false","lens": "false","season": "true","food": "true","size": "true"}
  {"arm": "false","lens": "true","season": "true","food": "true","size": "true"}
  {"arm": "true","lens": "true","season": "true","food": "true","size": "true"}
  {"arm": "true","lens": "true","season": "true","food": "false","size": "true"}
  {"arm": "true","lens": "true","season": "false","food": "false","size": "true"}
  and so on...
]
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: It is not javascript, but I read these threads in order to get the logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162254/all-possible-combinations-of-an-array. @adiga already solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 2D matrix with on and off switches for each property. Then create the entries for each key and create the object using `Object.fromEntries()`

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
etc
```

- You need a total of `2 ** keys.length` objects in the array. So, create that using `Array.from({ 2 ** keys.length })`
- In the map function, create a binary number for the current row using `row.toString(2)`
- Add the leading 0s until the string is `keys.length` long: (`"00001"`)
- split the string to make it an array (`["0", "0", "0", "0", "1"]`)
- map this array and create an array of entries for the corresponding key

  `[["arm","false"],["lens","false"],["season","false"],["food","false"],["size","false"]]`
- Create an object from the array of entries using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Here's a snippet:

```js
let keys = ['arm', 'lens', 'season', 'food', 'size'];

function combination(keys) {
  return Array.from({ length: 2 ** keys.length }, (_, row) =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      row.toString(2)
          .padStart(keys.length, 0)
          .split('')
          .map((binary, j) => [keys[j], String(Boolean(+binary))])
    )
  )
}

console.log(combination(keys))
```

Comment: You nailed it bro! Could you recommend me any topic or course to learn in order to be able to solve these kind of problems on my own? I am used to conventional front requesting data from ws, but I'd like to improve my solving logic problems skills. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We can build this on two reusable functions, like this:

```js
const crossproduct = (xss) =>
  xss.reduce ((ps, xs) => ps.reduce ((r, p) => [...r, ...(xs.map (x => [...p, x]))], []), [[]])

const mergeAll = xs => 
  Object.assign ({}, ...xs)

const combine = (properties, values) => 
  crossproduct (properties.map (p => values.map (v => ({[p]: v}))))
    .map (mergeAll)


const properties = ['arm', 'lens', 'season', 'food', 'size']
const values = [true, false]

console.log (combine (properties, values))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Our utility functions are:

- **`crossproduct`**, which takes an array of arrays and finds the cartesian product of them.  For instance,

  ```js
  crossproduct ([['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2], ['x', 'y']])
    //=> [["a", 1, "x"], ["a", 1, "y"], ["a", 2, "x"], ["a", 2, "y"], 
    //    ["b", 1, "x"], ["b", 1, "y"], ["b", 2, "x"], ["b", 2, "y"], 
    //    ["c", 1, "x"], ["c", 1, "y"], ["c", 2, "x"], ["c", 2, "y"]]
  ```
- and **`mergeAll`**, which combines an array of separate objects into one like this:

  ```js
  mergeAll ([{foo: 1}, {bar: 2}, {baz: 3}])
    //=> {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
  ```

  This is just a thin wrapper around `Object.assign`, simply applying it to an array rather than individual objects.

Our main function, `combine` first creates an array of arrays matching individual property names to values like this:

```js
  [
    [{"arm": true}, {"arm": false}], 
    [{"lens": true}, {"lens": false}], 
    [{"season": true}, {"season": false}], 
    [{"food": true}, {"food": false}], 
    [{"size": true}, {"size": false}]
]
```

This is the bit `properties.map (p => values.map (v => ({[p]: v})))`.  While that could be extracted as a stand-alone function, it doesn't seem to have any other uses, so the decision is simply a matter of code aesthetics.

We call `crossproduct` on that result, getting this intermediate format:

```js
[
  [{"arm": true}, {"lens": true}, {"season": true}, {"food": true}, {"size": true}], 
  [{"arm": true}, {"lens": true}, {"season": true}, {"food": true}, {"size": false}], 
  [{"arm": true}, {"lens": true}, {"season": true}, {"food": false}, {"size": true}], 
  [{"arm": true}, {"lens": true}, {"season": true}, {"food": false}, {"size": false}],
  // ... 
  [{"arm": false}, {"lens": false}, {"season": false}, {"food": false}, {"size": false}]
]
```

And finally, we call `.map (mergeAll)` on that array to get our final format.

Note that if you really have no other use for `mergeAll`, it's short and can easily be inlined in the main function as `.map (xs => Object.assign ({}, ...xs))`.  It's a function that I use often and would simply have in handy in my utility toolbox, so I personally wouldn't inline it.  You may feel differently.

---

Do notice the basic idea here.  We don't try to solve the problem in one go, but rather apply a series of transforms to get to our final format.  This allows us to take advantage of reusable functions for some of those steps.  It's a powerful technique.

Comment: Haven't crossed paths in a bit. Delightful decomposition results in fully reusable parts. This reminds me a lot of the steps required to build a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). I have a module sitting around maybe I'll add that one as an answer for fun

Comment: Very nice answer and justification, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Start building from empty array and add the 2 possibilities for key (true/false).
Repeat the process by traversing all keys, for each key take the available results from previous.

```js
let properties = ["arm", "lens", "season", "food", "size"];

const addTwo = (arr, key) => {
  const result = [];
  ["true", "false"].forEach((val) =>
    arr.forEach((item) => result.push({ ...item, [key]: val }))
  );
  return result;
};

const combinations = (arr) => {
  let output = [{}];
  arr.forEach((key) => (output = addTwo(output, key)));
  return output;
};

console.log(combinations(properties));
```

Comment: Clear and neat! Thank you very much!